# Why does the main function in objective-c preserve a C-style?

Tags: objective-c, c

This could sound a bit weird.

In `main.m`, it is written as such:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RTAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

which is a C-style main function (though with typical [class method] function call). But if we look at syntax of objective-C, one might think of something like this:

```
+(int)main:(int)argc :(char*) argv[] //I don't really know if (char*) argv[] will be legit in obj-c
{
        // DO SOMETHING
        return 0;
}
```

So I'm getting confused about the language itself. Does objective-c simply extends C-syntax? Or is it an independent language itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C. As such, you can (or at least, should be able to) compile any C program through an Objective-C compiler.

Knowing this, the ANSI C standard states that the correct declaration of main is either `int main(int argc, char** argv)` or `int main(void)`.

http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html